# Is it valid to compress web service responses with JSONP content?

Tags: javascript, jsonp

Simple question really, but not one I am able to find clear guidance on.  I'm writing web services that support JSONP responses (based on specification of a callback query param), and would like to provide support for compression.

I raised [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699484/servicestack-using-gzip-deflate-compression-with-jsonp-requests) a while back about a possible bug in ServiceStack, but before providing a fix for it, I'm looking for guidance on whether I should be in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Technically JSONP is javascript, not JSON.  I.e. [it should have `application/javascript` mimetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111302/best-content-type-to-serve-jsonp). And, just like any other JS resource a web page might request (e.g. a static `foo.js` file), it can be compressed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Kind of confirms my thinking that I need to fix some bugs (see other linked question above).  Would you expect a compressed response based on the definition of an `Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch` header?  Quick test in Fiddler suggests that's how a `foo.js` `application/javascript` request works.

Comment: Yeah, it should be handled just like any compressed request-response.  The compression negotiation is taking place as part of the HTTP request-response header negotiation, which is more or less independent of the type of data being transported.  JS, CSS, html... whatever - if you look at how these kinds of files are transported (and compressed), the headers will all look similar.